# Add a gradient colorband legend in plotly

Tags: colors, plotly, gradient

I'm using plotly, plotly express and plotly figure factory to plot U.S data. But I have an issue with color band.
1- Can I add a different color band from the original one? like a new type which is not based on the graph?
2- I want a gradient one but it shows a discrete one.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me.

=========================

```
    import plotly.figure_factory as ff

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_sample = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/laucnty16.csv')
df_sample['State FIPS Code'] = df_sample['State FIPS Code'].apply(lambda x: str(x).zfill(2))
df_sample['County FIPS Code'] = df_sample['County FIPS Code'].apply(lambda x: str(x).zfill(3))
df_sample['FIPS'] = df_sample['State FIPS Code'] + df_sample['County FIPS Code']

colorscale = ["#f7fbff","#ebf3fb","#deebf7","#d2e3f3","#c6dbef","#b3d2e9","#9ecae1",
              "#85bcdb","#6baed6","#57a0ce","#4292c6","#3082be","#2171b5","#1361a9",
              "#08519c","#0b4083","#08306b"]
endpts = list(np.linspace(1, 12, len(colorscale) - 1))
fips = df_sample['FIPS'].tolist()
values = df_sample['Unemployment Rate (%)'].tolist()

fig = ff.create_choropleth(
    fips=fips, values=values,
    binning_endpoints=endpts,
    colorscale=colorscale,
    show_state_data=False,
    show_hover=True, centroid_marker={'opacity': 0},
    asp=2.9, title='USA by Unemployment %',
    legend_title='% unemployed'
)

fig.layout.template = None
fig.write_image("fig1.png", scale=20)
fig.show()
```

=====================================enter image description here

Answer (score 0):

- I recommend moving to https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/
- figure generation is quicker
- uses a continuous color scale as you require
- provides much more flexible zoom and pan

#### data prep

```
import requests
import urllib
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# get geometry data as a geopandas dataframe
# fmt: off
src = [{"name": "counties", "suffix": ".shp", "url": "https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_county_20m.zip",},]
data = {}
for s in src:
    f = Path.cwd().joinpath(urllib.parse.urlparse(s["url"]).path.split("/")[-1])
    if not f.exists():
        r = requests.get(s["url"],stream=True,)
        with open(f, "wb") as fd: 
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128): fd.write(chunk)

    fz = ZipFile(f)
    fz.extractall(f.parent.joinpath(f.stem))

    data[s["name"]] = gpd.read_file(f.parent.joinpath(f.stem).joinpath([f.filename for f in fz.infolist() if Path(f.filename).suffix == s["suffix"]][0])).assign(source_name=s["name"])
gdf = pd.concat(data.values()).to_crs("EPSG:4326")

df_sample = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/laucnty16.csv')
df_sample['State FIPS Code'] = df_sample['State FIPS Code'].apply(lambda x: str(x).zfill(2))
df_sample['County FIPS Code'] = df_sample['County FIPS Code'].apply(lambda x: str(x).zfill(3))
df_sample['FIPS'] = df_sample['State FIPS Code'] + df_sample['County FIPS Code']

gdf2 = pd.merge(gdf, df_sample, left_on=["STATEFP","COUNTYFP"], right_on=["State FIPS Code","County FIPS Code"])
```

#### plot

```
colorscale = ["#f7fbff","#ebf3fb","#deebf7","#d2e3f3","#c6dbef","#b3d2e9","#9ecae1",
              "#85bcdb","#6baed6","#57a0ce","#4292c6","#3082be","#2171b5","#1361a9",
              "#08519c","#0b4083","#08306b"]


# build choropleth 
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(
    gdf2,
    geojson=gdf2.geometry,
    locations=gdf2.index,
    color="Unemployment Rate (%)",
    color_continuous_scale=colorscale,
    hover_data=["NAME", "FIPS"]
).update_layout(
    mapbox={"style": "white-bg", "zoom": 1.5, "center": {"lat": 50, "lon": -120}},
    margin={"l":0,"r":0,"t":30,"b":0},
    title='USA by Unemployment %',
    coloraxis_colorbar_title="Rate"
)

fig
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed to this but still I have those problems. Is there any possibility to add a customized color band?(I mean different colors and scales from the original data) like adding a new graph..

Comment: updated - assuming none standard terminology of color band means color scale.  or do you mean you want to drive the color from a completely different data attribute in the data frame?

Comment: if you mean density mapbox https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-density-heatmaps/ I have a solution for that too